# Run cabal repl from winghci

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci, winghci

To include Cabal dependencies I run `cabal install mypackage`

I then run `cabal repl` and from REPL use `import library`

This allows to use newly added library from GHCi.

Is same possible using WinGhci ? Run a WinGhci REPL which has access to installed Cabal dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:!` to execute shell commands. I.e. run `:!cabal install mypackage` from within the WinGHCi repl. But then you can't `import mypackage` until you restart WinGHCi. That's my experience at least. I'm interested in an answer as well...

Running `:!cabal repl` inside WinGHCi repl is just not sensible (which answers the title to your question literally).